PostgreSQL insert performance
I am trying to implement a "batch" insert into some PostgreSQL table using JDBC. The task is to insert data into some arbitrary table. Some rows could be inserted and some not due to the constraints and/or foreign keys violations and I have to handle this, lets say, by printing these rows to the log. Like, my app should take table name as a parameter and insert a bunch of data into it.
The app receives data from the external source in a format like:
<table name><row>...<row>
The data reception rate is high enough to be ignored.
Since I don't know the table's structure, I need to handle insertion errors for each row at runtime. I tried following approaches:



Transactions handling
Time for 1 million inserts on my computer




Autocommit on
12 minutes


Commit after each insert
20 minutes


Release/create savepoint before each insert, commit each 50k
25 minutes



For comparison, a pure insert with no error handling, using a committed batch size of 50k, takes 8 minutes.
And I really don't understand:

Why are "manual" commits almost twice as slow as auto commits? At least it could be explained by the fact that PostgreSQL server should keep a transaction for the period of time between insert and actual commit. But...
... Why savepoint is even slower than commits after each insert?
What could I do to speedup the process? I completely ran out of ideas. I thought about retrieving table data, like constraints, and check each row manually, but I suppose it is too complicated and will slow down the process even more.

I use a simple table:
CREATE TABLE groups
(
    id          INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(300),
    CONSTRAINT groups_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(300),
    group_id    INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_groups_fk FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (id)
);

INSERT INTO groups(id, name, description)
VALUES (0, 'Group0', 'Default group');

Code for savepoints
private static final String TEST_INSERT = """
        INSERT INTO users(id, name, description, group_id)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
        """;
private final static long TOTAL_SIZE = 1_000_000L;
private final static long BATCH_SIZE = 50_000L;

@Test
public void testSavepoints() {
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    Savepoint savepoint;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM users");
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(TEST_INSERT);
        savepoint = conn.setSavepoint("insert_sp");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Cannot prepare statement for insert", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    log.info("Started:");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        for (long i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++) {
            try {
                conn.releaseSavepoint(savepoint);
                savepoint = conn.setSavepoint("insert_sp");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Cannot set savepoint for insert", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try {
                stmt.setObject(1, i);
                stmt.setObject(2, "User " + i);
                stmt.setObject(3, "This is user #" + i);
                stmt.setObject(4, 0);
                if (i == 13)
                    stmt.setInt(4, -1);
                int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();
                if ((i % BATCH_SIZE) == 0) {
                    log.info("Committing batch: i={}", i);
                    conn.commit();
                    savepoint = conn.setSavepoint("insert_sp");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                try {
                    conn.rollback(savepoint);
                    savepoint = conn.setSavepoint();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    log.error("Cannot rollback savepoint/commit transaction", ex);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                log.error("Cannot insert #{} ({})", i, e.getErrorCode());
            }
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("Something went wrong: {}", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Cannot close connection", e);
        }
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long passed = end - start;
    log.info("Completed in {} ({})", passed, passed / 1000.0);
}

For auto commits and manual commits I use the same code without savepoint and with manual commit after each insert for the manual commit case.
I am quite new to PostgreSQL, but ran the same tests with Oracle and got 10 minutes for manual commits and 7 minutes for savepoints which looks more reasonable. I read that PostgreSQL isn't too good to handle many savepoints, but I use just one. Also, with Oracle I do not release savepoint but overwrite it, and turned out that PostgreSQL does not support that although it is standard.
The test environment is pretty simple - a PostgreSQL 17.2 server in the docker on the local machine and the test app is the only client connected to it:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:17.2
    container_name: postgres
    command: postgres -c logging_collector=on -c log_destination=stderr -c log_directory=/pgsql/var/log -c config_file=/pgsql/etc/postgresql.conf
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U postgres -d postgres'"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - PGDATA=/pgsql/var/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
      - '15432:5432'
    expose:
      - "5432"
      - "15432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/volume:/pgsql
    networks:
      - docker-network
...
networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "10.1.1.0/24"
          gateway: "10.1.1.1"

PostgreSQL config (with my attempts to optimize it)
$ grep -v '^\s*#' postgresql.conf |grep -v '^[ \t]*$'
listen_addresses = '*'
shared_buffers = 2GB
huge_pages = try
temp_buffers = 256MB
work_mem = 1GB
max_prepared_transactions = 512
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 512MB
default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
default_transaction_deferrable = off



If you want to speed this up use COPY. In Postgres 17+ you now have ON_ERROR to deal with rejected rows and keep on with the command. In 16- COPY the command is all or none, either all rows are entered or an error rolls everything back. 2) There is also INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ad shown here INSERT. It will deal with UNIQUE constraints but not FK errors. 3) Lastly a popular option is to dump data into a staging table w/o constraints and then move from there.


Sorry, forgot to mention that i receive data row by row from the external source, not from file.

Add that information as update to question text, with more detail, e.g. ingestion rate, size of rows, etc.

And i don’t understand how could intermediate temporary table help.  Like, i have to create it, then to insert data to it, then to copy data from it to the actual table with constraints. Could you explain please? Thank you!

incoming data rate is quite fast thus could be ignored. Like, let’s assume data are available immediately, like in the test code. The size of row you could observe in the table’s ddl in the question. At the other hand, as I mentioned it’s just for testing, the app should handle any given table

Looks like network latency. The additional BEGIN and COMMIT statements, for each INSERT, cause delay. When you also add a savepoint, it gets even worse. How many concurrent processes do you use to run the import? Or is it just one process using one database connection?

Do you mean the latency between app and postgres? Postgres is in the docker on the same machine. Sorry, not sure I understand. The test environment is pretty simple - a postgres server in the docker on the local machine and the test app is the only client connected to it.

The poor performance is due to performing row-by-row inserts instead of bulk inserts. Oracle has a SAVE EXCEPTIONS option when performing bulk inserts that facilitates processing unvalidated code; unfortunately, PostgreSQL lack a comparable mechanism. Unique constraint conflicts can be somewhat handled with ON CONCFLICT, but handling invalid foreign key references in the input data requires a much more complicated approach.

copy doesn't need to read from an actual file, nor does it require the whole batch to come in all at once - it can gobble it up row by row. Most high performance batch insert methods in Postgres-compatible ORMs and client libs/tools are implemented using copy.

3 times as many commands (BEGIN, INSERT..., COMMIT) means 3 times as many context switches, IPC, etc.  It is not at all surprising that this would lead to a slow down.

With an intermediate table, you can validate the constraint conditions in SQL (the same language they are written in).  While this is a pain, it should be much better than trying to validate them in Java.

It's not just a pain but it's about the speed as well. All inserts/updates will be performed twice. And I really don't understand how could it help with constraints validation.

@BUKTOP If you partition the main table, you can import data into a separate table, deal with invalid rows, then attach it as a partition - zero rewrites. You can even wrap your source with a foreign data wrapper - zero writes, period. You can combine these and let it lazy-load. As to doing things twice, you're comparing 3 operations for each of 20 batches to writing/moving the payload twice in-db; the one additional rewrite from a temp/unlogged table might end up being cheaper than the overhead around processing the chunks, especially if you plan to validate on the fly, on either end.
